# Redirect file only once

Tags: php, javascript, session, cookies

Is is possible to redirect to a file 2 times then for a third times it redirect to somewhere else

EX:/index.php redirect to /index2.php then /index2.php redirect to /index.php.....,,,, then for the second times we visit /index.php it will redirect us to other file?

can we do this with javascript or PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**index.php** redirets to **index2.php**

**index2.php** redirects to **index.php**`?r=1`

in index.php check:

```
if($_GET['r']==1){
    //redirect to other page
}
```

**UPDATE**

As I understood you have this redirects:

```
1. Somewhere => index.php
2. index.php => site.com
3. site.com  => index.php // and in this step you need to redirect to other place
```

So just add check:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.referrer == 'site.com'){
    location.href = 'OTHER PAGE ADDRESS';
}
else{
    location.href = 'site.com';
}
</script>
```

So if user came from other site he will redirect to site.com if he from site.com when to other place.

Comment: Sorry i think i ask the wrong question i only have control over 1 redirection so i can only control 1 file EX:http://site.com/redirect1 redirect to mysite/index.php then mysite/index.php redirect to site.com/redirect1 so right now i use javascript to redirect setInterval(function(){document.location="site.com/redirect1"},3500); but this end up like squirrel in a wheel :P

Comment: In this case you can use `document.referrer` and check if it from site.com redirect to different place.

Comment: You don't need counter. I updated the question, let me know if I understood your question wrong.

Comment: for some unknown reason document.referrer can't be detected how can i combine url+document.location.hash.slice

Comment: You can always use PHP `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: Thanks for this i have to use header right? header("mysite.com"); but i can't use header anymore because in my case header already set from other file so any other idea? Thanks

Comment: no just save PHP referer value in JS variable and do redirect by js. `var jsVar = "<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']?>";`

Comment: Sorry so how can i combine with the document.referrer code above? Thanks

Comment: Replace document.referrer with variable I wrote in comment before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can add a counter in a session variable to track the redirection. After each redirect, increment the counter.

When the counter reach its limit, perform your desired action.

Comment: set $_SESSION[counter] = 0; 
Just before redirect increment the counter like this: 
$_SESSION[counter] += 1; 
header('Location:index.php'); 

Now on another page you can check the value of session variable.

Comment: i only have control to 1 file possible to combine both in 1 file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The question is how permanent you want it.

JAVASCRIPT:

If you want to do it with javascript then take a look at
`window.location`
and to remember whether user was on the first page just use JavaScript cookies.
Simple tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm
You can also set an expiration.

PHP:

If you want to make it "less permanent" for example just for one opened browser window or something like that then look at PHP session management
http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Answer (score 0):

i have written the code for index.php?re_id =

mention re_id on each page. n you can give more conditions

```
 if($_GET['re_id']){

     $re_id = $_GET['re_id'];   
      if($re_id=="1")
      {
      header("location:index3.php");
      }
      else
      {
         header("location:index2.php");
     }
}
```

Comment: i can only control 1 file so this still possible?

Comment: if header already set from another file can we still set another header? in my code have this 
include('main.php'); <== the header already set here